# Can we integrate Paypal Payment Gateway with IONIC 1 or 2 app if yes then how...?

Tags: android, angularjs, ionic-framework, paypal, ionic2

I have developed a mobile application for Android & iOS using IONIC framework. Now I want to integrate Payment Gateway with the same app.

I have gone through multiple links, but didn't get a final answer it is it possible to integrate Paypal with IONIC or not.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to implement PayPal to ionic IOS app, You can use inApp purchase plugin from Cordova to use for payment.

You can find it in below mentioned link.
https://github.com/AlexDisler/cordova-plugin-inapppurchase

Comment: And what about PayPal with Android.

Comment: you can use inApp purchase plugin for android

Answer (score 0):

You can use [PayPal-Cordova-Plugin](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Cordova-Plugin).

> The PayPal SDK Cordova/Phonegap Plugin adds support for the PayPal SDK on iOS and Android platforms. It uses the native PayPal Mobile SDK libraries, which you must also download

Answer (score 0):

This is created by me and successfully work in ionic 1 you can try this:

https://github.com/hitarthiCreole/ionic-paypal-sdk-demo

for a other reference you can also go through this:

http://ionicandroidlearning.blogspot.in/2015/11/ionic-paypal-integration.html

https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Cordova-Plugin#your-app-integration

Comment: Thanks @Hitarthi for your support, we will implement it and get back to you.

Comment: If it is helpful then please accept this answer@PremkumarAgrawal